# Best way to eval in a given scope / context which is in the form of a Dict?

Tags: julia

I have a string, e.g. `z[2]` and I want to `eval` it in a context, e.g. `Dict(:z => 1:10)`

What's the best way to do it?

I can make it sort of work, but it is very slow.

```
function replace_expr(expr, d::Dict)
    return expr
end

function replace_expr(s::Symbol, d::Dict)
    get(d, s, s)
end

function replace_expr(expr::Expr, d::Dict)
    return Expr(replace_expr(expr.head, d),
                [replace_expr(e, d) for e in expr.args]...)
end


function eval_with(context::Dict{Symbol, Any}, expr_string::AbstractString)
    # E.g. :abc => :(s[:abc])
    d = Dict(k => :(s[$(Meta.quot(k))]) for k in keys(context))
    ex = parse("s -> $expr_string")
    ex = replace_expr(ex, d)
    return eval(ex)(context)
end
```

The following is the test

```
function make_context()
    x = 1
    y = "foo"
    z = 2:5

    Dict(
        :x => x,
        :y => y,
        :z => z
    )
end

const context = make_context()

@test eval_with(context, "x + 3") == 4
@test eval_with(context, "string(1, y, 1)") == "1foo1"
@test eval_with(context, "z[2]") == 3

@time eval_with(context, "z[2]")
# 0.004739 seconds (767 allocations: 40.728 KB)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a place where you can lean upon more of Julia's built-in expression evaluation machinery.  `eval` takes an optional argument: the module in which the evaluation is to occur.

You can create new modules programmatically:

```
julia> M = Module()
anonymous
```

And you can assign values from a dictionary into that module with `eval`:

```
julia> context = Dict(
               :x => 1,
               :y => "foo",
               :z => 2:5
           );

julia> for (k,v) in context
           eval(M, :($k = $v))
       end

julia> M.x
1

julia> M.y
"foo"
```

And now, of course, you can evaluate your custom string within the context of your module.

```
julia> eval(M, parse("x+3"))
4

julia> eval(M, parse("string(1, y, 1)"))
"1foo1"
```

Dynamic evaluation like this is not going to be a place where Julia shines. I think this will be about as good as it gets:

```
julia> @time eval(M, parse("z[2]"))
  0.000284 seconds (13 allocations: 672 bytes)
3
```

Note that this has slightly different semantics from the code you wrote above; the variables within your context only got populated at the beginning… and might be changed by a new evaluation.

And the [usual](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/sbg7J8W6GFg/h8EJn6pk2YUJ) [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882241/eval-in-function-scope-accessing-function-args) about using `eval` apply.  There are often other, better ways of structuring your program that will be more performant, more understandable, and more maintainable.

Comment: That's already a huge improvement. I tried `eval(M, :(const $k = $v))` also, unfortunately it doesn't help further.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the values in advance, you can get around using eval via metaprogramming. A macro for this is provided by Parameters.jl:

```
d = Dict{Symbol,Any}(:a=>5.0,:b=>2,:c=>"Hi!")
@unpack a, c = d
a == 5.0 #true
c == "Hi!" #true
```